# Is there a Oracle SQL function to return a row with columns based on different different values in one column?

Tags: sql, oracle

| id | datacode | datavalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | man | Y |
| 100 | employed | N |
| 100 | married | Y |
| 101 | man | N |
| 101 | employed | Y |
| 101 | married | Y |

If i had a table like below, is there any function that allows me to have a row that only returns columns the id, man, married where the value of man and married equal its respective datavalue without self joining.

The desired outcome is as follows:

| id | man | married |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Y | Y |
| 101 | N | Y |

Comment: Is there a reason you must use a key/value table? They are a nuisance to work with. Why not just a person table with the columns man, employed and married instead? That would make this a lot easier (`select id, man, married from person` in your case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle transposing text value rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764683/oracle-transposing-text-value-rows-to-columns). Or more general [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1):

Try `max(case...)` in combination with `group by`.

```
select id, 
       max(CASE WHEN datacode = 'man' THEN datavalue ELSE null END) as man,
       max(CASE WHEN datacode = 'married' THEN datavalue ELSE null END) as married
from mytable
group by id;
```

The aggregate function `max()` is working on groups, and it will filter out `null` values - what we create with the `case` statement for non-matching rows. The result is one row for each id.

Comment: Yep, conditional aggreation is the typical way to deal with key/value tables. `ELSE null` is the default and can hence be left out. If you want the results ordered by id, add `` ORDER BY id`.

Comment: this is just an example, as i have a data set with many different data code and its corresponding data values for an id. For example, datacode: ic, hp number, address, income, etc.  but i want columns of datacode group by id, i am thinking that pivot would do the trick?

Comment: I think both approaches work, try to make a performance comparison - and let me know the result, I'm curious!

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use pivot clause for that purpose like below :

```sql
with sample_data(id, datacode, datavalue) as (
select 100, 'man'       , 'Y' from dual union all
select 100, 'employed'  , 'N' from dual union all
select 100, 'married'   , 'Y' from dual union all
select 101, 'man'       , 'N' from dual union all
select 101, 'employed'  , 'Y' from dual union all
select 101, 'married'   , 'Y' from dual 
)
select *
from sample_data t
pivot (
max(DATAVALUE) for DATACODE in (
    'man' as man
--  , 'employed' as employed
  , 'married' as married
  ) 
)
;
```